# Scripting query issue in join query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am facing issue in SQL query and need some help.

I am newbie in Php and sql. So any help would be aprreciated.

I have the following Sql query and tries.

```
 $insert_on_duplicate_update_query = "INSERT INTO test (`store_client_id`,`customer_id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`,`created_on`,`updated_on`,dob) VALUES('1','123','abc','xyz','abc@hotmail.com','2018-10-12 00:00:02','2018-10-12 00:00:02','NULL') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `store_client_id`='1',`customer_id`='123',`first_name`='abc',`last_name`='xyz',`email`='abc@hotmail.com',`updated_on`='2018-10-12 00:00:02',dob='null';";

  $insert_on_duplicate_update_query = str_replace(array("'NULL'","'null'"), null, $insert_on_duplicate_update_query);


 echo $insert_on_duplicate_update_query;
```

So here i want to replace 'NULL' to NULL in the follow place -

```
 VALUES('1','123','abc','xyz','abc@hotmail.com','2018-10-12 00:00:02','2018-10-12 00:00:02','NULL')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change in str_replace() function on second line.

It should be as below.

```
$insert_on_duplicate_update_query = str_replace(array("'NULL'","'null'"), 'null', $insert_on_duplicate_update_query);
```

Hope it make sense

Answer (score 5):

Just need to change second parameter in str_replace function as bellow.

```
`$str = "abc = 'NULL'";
$a = str_replace("'NULL'", 'NULL', $str);
echo ($a);`
```

Second parameter with '' quotes.